# How to make sums and divisions between columns to change the value of an existing column in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, calculation, chunks, divide-by-zero

I have a large file with millions of rows and 158 columns. The values in the file have different type: str, int, inf, float, zeros and empty cells... and I'm reading the file in chunks:

```
 DB = pd.read_csv(dbChr, chunksize=1000, delimiter='\t', decimal =',', index_col=False)
```

I need to make some basic operations between two columns to change/update, the value of an existing column.

To make this operations, my file have a header with the columns name. A little example (in the real data I there are more columns between them)

```
 CHROM     POS     REF     GT_11     GT_01     GT_00     MAF     pato_MAF     pato_MAF_G
 chr1      10       A       0          88       450       0         0            0     
 chr1      10       T       0          56       0         0      2,4346          0
 chr1      11       G       15          0       0         0      2,4346
```

In the example there're many situations that I have to deal with. In the column pato_MAF, pato refers to pathology, so I will have different columns of this type like: `cancer_MAF`, `derma_MAF`, ..., until 28. And the same with `pato_MAF_G`

The operation I have to do to update the value of MAF column:

```
 MAF = (GT_11 + (GT_01/2))/ GT_00
```

When the value of `GT_00` is 0 a have a problem.

Then, with that value of `MAF`, I have to update the value of `pato_MAF_G`, as the subtraction of:

```
 pato_MAF_G = MAF - pato_MAF
```

I have tried these:

```
 for chunk in DB:

        chunk['MAF'] = (chunk['GT_11'] + (chunk['GT_01'])/2)/chunk['GT_00']

        for pato in pato_list:

             chunk['MAF_'+pato] = (chunk[pato+'_GT_11'] + chunk[pato+'_GT_01']/2)/chunk[pato+'_GT_00']

             chunk['MAF_'+pato+'_G'] = chunk['MAF'] - chunk['MAF_'+pato]

 mafdb = chunk.to_csv(mafDbChr, sep = "\t", index = False, header = False )
```

But in the resulting file I have some empty files or the order of the columns has changed... Moreover, if I have a 0 as denominator, I get an error.

How could I deal with these? Thanks!

Comment: You can use div function in pandas to avoid the error of 0 as denominator. See:
[1]: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.div.html